# Mutex.WaitAll and Semaphore.WaitOne at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a multi threaded program, where I have an array of Mutexes that I want to do a WaitAll on. But at the same time I also want to be able to receive a signal on a Semaphore. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
Mutex.WaitAll(arrMutexes) || semSignal.WaitOne()
```

The Mutexes tells me that all my sub threads are idle, while the Semaphore can be signaled from another process.

Is there a way to do this without using a loop? I would also like to be able to tell if it was the Mutexes or the Semaphore that was signaled, if possible.

EDIT: 
Explanation of the process:

The sub threads are performing some work, and may be dependent on one or more of the other threads to be alive. Therefor I can only terminate the threads when they are all idle. The Semaphore can be signaled from another process to tell this process to terminate even if all process are not idle.

Comment: 'The mutexes tell me that all my sub threads are idle' sounds a bit dubious, but I guess you could achieve what you seem to want with an extra thread that does the waitAll on the mutex array and signals a WaitOne on two semaphores..?

Comment: I don't think you can in one statement, but perhaps you can [WaitHandle.WaitAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitany) on one mutex and the semaphore, then, if that succeeds, acquire that mutex and continue with the next mutex/semaphore wait, and so on.

Comment: @MartinJames Your suggestion with the extra thread did the job. If you submit the suggestion as an answer, I will gladly accept it, since it solved my problem. I have added a little to the question to try to explain the process.

Comment: Mutex and Semaphore both derive from WaitHandle.  Intentionally, that lets you use WaitHandle.WaitAny/All() to get what you want.  Do not waste an entire thread on just a wait, that's gross.

Comment: @HansPassant The challenge is that I need to wait for all the Mutexes to be signaled OR the semaphore to be signaled.

Comment: Just use WaitAny().  If the return value tells you that it was a mutex that completed then remove and repeat.

Comment: @HansPassant... yeah..ish.   That means shuffling/recreating the mutex array each time one is acquired at the cost of two context changes per signal by introducing the loop that the OP specifically wished to avoid.....or OP could use a design that is likely to work straightaway without extended test/debug:)

Comment: @HansPassant The difference is that WaitAll doesn't obtain any of the mutexes until it can obtain all of them at once, and that is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your desire by creating another 'mutexWait' thread whose sole purpose is to waitAll on the array of mutexes and, when that is satisfied, signals a  'mutexesAquired' semaphore.

Your existing thread can then WaitOne on mutexesAquired and your inter-process semaphore, the returned result then indicates which signal has been fired in the 'usual' way.